# Lightning Community Builder - Page Metadata

Tags: lightning, migration-tool, community-builder

I have been given a Lightning Community site to work on that has been built on the Customer Service (Napili) Spring '17 template. The community contains a number of custom pages, and I want to retrieve the metadata for these pages using either the Force IDE or the migration tool.

I was expecting the pages to be accessible as flexipages, but they do not seem to appear. Are Lightning community pages stored in a different object, and is that object accessible with the API?

Comment: did you fins a solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 metadata types that define a community:

> 1. [Network](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_network.htm?search_text=network) - Contains Community Management configuration elements
> 2. [CustomSite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sites.htm?search_text=CustomSite) - Domain and page setting information (indexPage,
>      siteAdmin, URL)
> 3. [SiteDotCom](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sitedotcom.htm?search_text=SiteDotCom) - a binary file of your community layout. (Same
>      file produced by the Site.com Export)

As you can see, this is stored in the SiteDotCom Metadata type, since it is a binary file, we are unable to actually obtain an xml file with the page layout description/composition.

Knowledge Article on [Deploying Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000250156&type=1&language=en_US)

Answer (score 3):

No need to fully dig into the metadata to get these. You can export these pages from Community Builder, and then add them to either a Change Set (e.g. sandbox-->Production) or to a package (for transferring between unconnected orgs).

In Community Builder, click the Gear icon on the left, Select the Developer tab, and export the page. Once you do that, you can reuse these pages in the same org (just create a new page in any Community driven by community builder) or add them to a change set or package.

Full documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/community_builder_export_page.htm