# Deploy/retrieve lightning community page variations with metadata API?

Tags: lightning, metadata-api, lightning-community, lightning-bolt

I could not find an answer to this question in the documentation or by looking here.

I have built a page variation in my lightning community, and then exported it. I am fine including that in a managed/unmanaged package but I was wondering if it was also possible to deploy or retrieve that object via the metadata API?
There is a type called FlexiPage but I believe those are for Lightning Experience page layouts.

That way I could check it in a version control repository or have it part of a development deployment cycle where I could deploy the code to test it instead of installing a new managed package every time?

I could not find it either in the Unsupported Metadata types section of the documentation.

Similar question here with no answer: [Lightning Community Builder - Page Metadata](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163738/lightning-community-builder-page-metadata)

Thanks

Comment: i think that is stored in the sitedotcom, this is what you will have to deploy in your package.xml

Comment: I think starting Summer 2017 you can migrate communities using changeset?. Did you try that option or do you want to do it only using metadata API?

Comment: It is mostly to be able to really deploy/retrieve from a local repository on my computer and not from one organization to/from a sandbox unfortunately :(

Comment: so what we do in our project is similar to what glls said we use sitedotcom to retrieve the community and then goto the target environment site and import this file. the reason we do this is because when we directly deployed sitedotcom using ant we got internal server error. we raised a case with salesforce and unfortunately this is the work around they suggested. So we move all lightning components,classes and all metadata related to communities pages using ant. retrieve our site using sitedotcom meta and then overwrite just the site part manually in target environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am looking for a solution I could automate :(

Out of curiosity, are you able to retrieve Lightning Bolt page variations with this process?

Answer (score 0):

That must help.
To enable ExperienceBundle, in Setup, select Enable ExperienceBundle Metadata API in Digital Experiences | Settings

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please follow these steps to download "Lightning Bold Pages" in Eclipse:

- Add "FlexiPage" type in your package.xml, just like you for downloading any other metadata types.
- **Set the version of the your package.xml file to 40.0.**
- Create a new folder named "flexipages" under "src" folder in project.
- Right click on "flexipages" -> Force.com -> Refresh from Server

Comment: From the Salesforce documentation on FlexiPage Metadata API: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Lightning pages are used in several places.
In the Salesforce app, a Lightning page is the home page for an app that appears in the navigation menu.
In Lightning Experience, Lightning pages can be used as the home page for an app, to customize the layout of record pages and the Home page, and as the utility bar for a Lightning app. >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
 Which is not what I am looking for *Deploy/retrieve lightning community page variations*