# Which metadata stores custom CSS for a community?

Tags: community, metadata-api, css, metadata, site.com

When creating a community, you can override the CSS of a template.

> Use custom CSS to override the default template and Branding panel styles. We recommend that you use custom CSS sparingly, because future releases of template components might not support all CSS customizations.

I'd like to backup my custom CSS in source control. I've seen [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163738/lightning-community-builder-page-metadata) post on getting metadata for a community. Following it, I did wildcards on `CommunityThemeDefinition` and `CommunityThemeDefinition` as well, assuming my CSS is stored in on of those metadata types.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CommunityTemplateDefinition</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CommunityThemeDefinition</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomSite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Network</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SiteDotCom</name>
    </types>
    <version>43.0</version>
</Package>
```

I didn't see any CSS in what was returned. In fact, no metadata folders with names similar to `CommunityThemeDefinition` and `CommunityThemeDefinition` were in the source that I pulled using `package.xml`. My `siteDotComSites` folder had a binary file, but I don't want to trust that it contains my custom CSS.

For those of you who are not aware, to override template CSS, you need to go into the Theme Settings in Builder, like so:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sad truth is, virtually the entirety of the configuration you can do in Community Builder is saved in that monolithic binary.

If you want to know whether to "trust" that the binary contains your custom CSS...

1. Spin up a sandbox.
2. Open Community Builder in the sandbox and verify what you see in the
   CSS.
3. Change the CSS in the sandbox.
4. Create a change set from production to sandbox containing the
   Community binary.
5. Deploy, and check again what you see in CSS for the sandbox.

Comment: The CSS is stored in the site binary.

Comment: Sorry to hear. At least now we know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also link your CSS in the Advanced > Head Markup  settings to a static resource.

Comment: How can I do this?